# Find JavaScript function definition in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome's Developer Tools rock, but one thing they don't seem to have (that I could find) is a way to find a JavaScript function's definition. This would be super handy for me because I'm working on a site that includes many external JS files. Sure grep solves this but in the browser would be much better. I mean, the browser has to know this, so why not expose it? What I expected was something like:

- Select 'Inspect Element' from page, which highlights the line in the Elements tab
- Right-click the line and select 'Go to function definition'
- Correct script is loaded in the Scripts tab and it jumps to the function definition

First off, does this functionality exist and I'm just missing it?

And if it doesn't, I'm guessing this would come from WebKit, but couldn't find anything for [Developer Tool feature requests](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list?can=2&q=javascript+function+definition&colspec=ID+Pri+Mstone+ReleaseBlock+Area+Feature+Status+Owner+Summary&cells=tiles) or [WebKit's Bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=javascript+function+definition).

Comment: There is a search bar that greps the current file in the Scripts tab and you can peek at the contents of a function by printing it. But I am now curios if there is a way to do a more general search like you want...

Comment: With the Google Chrome Developer Tools, at the "Sources" Tap -> right window you have to possibility to set "Event Breakpoints".

Comment: In my case I had a variable set to an unknown function. I did myvar.toString() and it printed: "function Object() { [native code] }" which is all I needed to know.

Answer (score 410, accepted):

Lets say we're looking for function named **`foo`**:

1. (open Chrome dev-tools),
2. Windows: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, or macOS:
   <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>optn</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. This opens a window for searching across all scripts.
3. check "Regular expression" checkbox,
4. search for **`foo\s*=\s*function`** (searches for `foo = function` with any number of spaces between those three tokens),
5. press on a returned result.

Another variant for function definition is **`function\s*foo\s*\(`** for `function foo(` with any number of spaces between those three tokens.

Comment: This is only one way to define a function named **`foo`**. There are others. What if our function is e.g. `bar['foo']`? (There's no good answer to that question, as far as I know --- it's essentially "don't write convoluted code")

Comment: add the OS X shortcut in the answer or explicitely specify what platform ctrl-shift-f is meant for

Comment: @zplesivcak I don't know to what platforms <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> applies

Comment: I couldn't find "function definition" using the selected answer. I have searched on Google and couldn't find any help.  (Using Chrome Version 41.0.2272.118 m )

Comment: And then you fail to find function declarations, dynamically generated function expressions and anonymous (unnamed) functions. I'd rather want something like Firefox: Click the function reference in the watch panel -> Jump to the function reference.

Comment: In Chrome 46.0.2490.86 m under Windows 10 I had to double-escape the special characters in the regex, e.g., **`foo\\s*=\\s*function`**

Comment: @FagnerBrack There's no perfect solution that I'm aware of, and Chrome now has functionality like that too, but the reference has to exist in scope when you're searching for it for that trick to work. I think this regex handles the situations you mentioned (except anonymous functions, which.. I mean, just search for "function" if you want to see them):
    
    `^(?=.*foo)(?=.*function).*$`

Also, the answer above is technically a perfect answer to the question, with some bonus info thrown in.

Comment: Note the regex above won't find arrow functions assigned to a variable like `var foo = () => (...)`, but that should be pretty rare.

@StevenLu This is pedantic, but I believe the function is not __named__ foo in your second example. It's assigned to the foo property on bar.

Comment: This doesn't work as the function is either not defined that way or is not coming up in search, as just searching for the function name shows only 1/1 result which is only in the HTML tag onclick call (no matter where or how I search from). I'm not sure how to find this function's definition without scouring every included .js file, which I thought were already included in this kind of search.

Comment: The answer seems to be outdated, nothing happens if I click that key combination in the developer console.

Comment: Correct @Black, nothing happens, it is an old answer and Chrome moved on.

Comment: Re the outdated comments above: I'm using the latest version of Chromium and CTRL + SHIFT + F still does work

Answer (score 93):

This [landed in Chrome on 2012-08-26](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=94932)
Not sure about the exact version, I noticed it in Chrome 24.

A screenshot is worth a million words:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools > Console > Show Function Definition]

I am inspecting an object with methods in the Console. Clicking on the "Show function definition" takes me to the place in the source code where the function is defined. Or I can just hover over the `function () {` word to see function body in a tooltip. You can easily inspect the whole prototype chain like this! CDT definitely rock!!!

Hope you all find it helpful!

Comment: Is there a shortcut or a function which will allows to search by a function reference? like ">inspect(document.body)". For now I have to d > tmp={a:myFunc}; >tmp, followed by the "Show function definition"

Comment: I think you can do `dir(myFunc)`

Comment: dir(myFunc) is much better, but still need two clicks and mouse

Comment: Oh, you mean if you can do it completely from keyboard? Something like `findDefinition(myFunc)`? AFAIK that doesn't exist yet...

Comment: If you don't have an object containing the function, you can create an object around it and it will still work. E.g. in the console type: `({1:somefunction})`, then right click the function inside the printed object.

Comment: @Protectorone you can just type dir(someFunction) into the console

Comment: @DP Yes, but that will just show the definition, not take you to where it is actually defined. The latter is more useful, because you can live edit it.

Comment: @Protectorone no, `console.dir()` always prints its argument as on object with properties so you can right-click on it and select "Show function definition"

Comment: There's no object in my case, all I have is HTML: `onclick=some_function(weird)`. The only search result no matter what I try just shows the HTML tag, though the function is doing... something... and isn't a pre-defined JavaScript function.

Comment: You should be able to inspect the element, then go to DOM Listeners in the right panel and find the click handler there. You can also use the Visual Event Chrome extension to make searching for the right handler faster.

Comment: Oddly, clicking show function definition does nothing for me.  Non-responsive.

Comment: I wonder if that function got garbage-collected by the time you're trying to inspect it

Answer (score 56):

You can print the function by evaluating the name of it in the console, like so

```
> unknownFunc
function unknownFunc(unknown) {
    alert('unknown seems to be ' + unknown);
}
```

this won't work for built-in functions, they will only display `[native code]` instead of the source code.

**EDIT**: this implies that the function has been defined within the current scope.

Comment: @futzlarson When I do this, the source and line is printed clear to the right on the same line as the function's closing brace.

Comment: This works for finding the currently active definition of the function.

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works, as of at least a couple months ago.  Instead you just get a very unhelpful `function unknownFunc(unknown)` line now, with no inline code.

Comment: @aroth At least in Chrome 45, this works again. I'm aware that things changed somewhere inbetween when this was posted and now. Conclusively, it seems to work again.

Comment: This merely shows 'undefined' even though clicking the button that calls the function does stuff from some source code I can't find anywhere... is there some magical scope wizard waving his wand somewhere and how do I find him?

Answer (score 39):

**2016 Update**: in Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103

There is a `Go to member` shortcut (listed in `settings > shortcut > Text Editor`). Open the file containing your function (in the `sources` panel of the DevTools) and press:

> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

or in OS X:

> <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

This enables to list and reach members of the current file.

Comment: well, what this seems to do is not "go to definition" of an arbitrary function call, but "show you all the function names in the current file and let you go to them" - which is kinda useful too.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, a feature similar to firefox! In firefox you can simply open the dev tools, hit Ctrl+f, and it will search for the JS function in all panes(HTML/CSS/Javascript/etc.). This does it, unlike the regex features mentioned in other answers.

Comment: @Randy, on which version of chrome? Which OS? I use Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 on OS X and it works fine.

Comment: @arthur.sw Sorry, I did not realise you had to be in sources for this to work. I expected it to work in the console as well.

Comment: For me a chrome menu opens if I press that key combination in the dev console.

Comment: @Black Just to make sure:
1. Focus (click) on the source files where you want to look for the function, in the source panel of the dev tools. 
2. It's the letter 'O', not the number '0'.

Comment: Is it the case that the "go to member" functionality only searches through sources that are currently opened in a Dev Tools tab? I just searched a function that couldn't be found, but after opening the source in which it is defined (using the evaluate, mouse-click method…), it was able to find it.

Comment: @Protectorone, yes

Answer (score 20):

Another way to navigate to the location of a function definition would be to break in debugger somewhere you can access the function and enter the functions fully qualified name in the console. This will print the function definition in the console and give a link which on click opens the script location where the function is defined.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Different browsers do this differently.

1. First open console window by right clicking on the page and selecting "Inspect Element", or by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd>.
2. In the console, type...

   - Firefox

     ```
     functionName.toSource()
     ```
   - Chrome

     ```
     functionName
     ```

Comment: the function I'm searching for is stop() and it is used as onmouseover="this.stop();" when I do what you say, it returns:
stop() { [native code] } So what to do now?

Comment: `functionName.toSource()` also works on latest chrome versions.

Comment: @Tarik Look at the online documentation for the builtin `stop`.

Answer (score 9):

in Chrome console:

```
debug(MyFunction)
MyFunction()
```

Comment: I like that. Noteworthy: do a `undebug(MyFunction)` to remove the breakpoint again (after you found the method implementation)

Comment: On Edge Developer tool, one doesn't have to write debug.
Just enter the function name on console. 
On the console itself it shows the function body, just click on that it takes you to the function.

Answer (score 6):

I find the quickest way to locate a global function is simply:

1. Select **Sources** tab.
2. In the **Watch** pane click **+** and type **window**
3. Your global function references are listed first, alphabetically.
4. Right-click the function you are interested in.
5. In the popup menu select **Show function definition**.
6. The source code pane switches to that function definition.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem finding the source of an object's method. The object name was `myTree` and its method was `load`. I put a breakpoint on the line that the method was called. By reloading the page, the execution stopped at that point. Then on the DevTools console, I typed the object along with the method name, i.e. `myTree.load` and hit Enter. The definition of the method was printed on the console:

[image]

Also, by right click on the definition, you can go to its definition in the source code:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Google chrome, Inspect element tool you can view any Javascript function definition.

1. Click on the Sources tab. Then select the index page. Search for the
   function.

[image]

2. Select the function then Right-click on the function and select
   "Evaluate selected text in console."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are already debugging, you can **hover over the function** and the *tooltip* will allow you to navigate directly to the function definition:

[image: Chrome Debugger Function Tooltip / Datatip]

**Further Reading**:

- [Chrome DevTools > JavaScript Debugging Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference)

Answer (score 0):

You encounter VM defined JS function ,you can try this command in Chrome console panel below.
Like this:
foo function name is `window.P.execute`

```
>window.P.execute.toString()
<'function(d,h){function n(){var a=null;e?a=h:"function"===typeof h&&(p.start=w(),a=h.apply(f,wa(d,k,l)),p.end=w());if(b){H[d]=a;a=d;for(da[a]=!0;(z[a]||[]).length;)z[a].shift()();delete z[a]}p.done=!0}var k=g||this;"function"===typeof d&&(h=d,d=E);b&&(d=d?d.replace(ha,""):"__NONAME__",V.hasOwnProperty(d)&&k.error(q(", reregistered by ",q(" by ",d+" already registered",V[d]),k.attribution),d),V[d]=k.attribution);for(var l=[],m=0;m<a.length;m++)l[m]=\na[m].replace(ha,"");var p=B[d||"anon"+ ++xa]={depend:l,registered:w(),namespace:k.namespace};d&&ya.hasOwnProperty(d);c?n():ua(l,k.guardFatal(d,n),d);return{decorate:function(a){U[d]=k.guardFatal(d,a)}}}'
```

so we got full function code.

Answer (score 0):

In **Chrome Dev Tools** (F12) you could also navigate to the method source from its **prototype definition**:

[image: method definition prototype]