# Is it possible to search with regular expressions within Chrome's developer console?

Tags: regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to search with regular expressions within Google Chrome's developer console? I know how to search for text within the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>), but can't see any way to enable regular expressions.

Do there e.g. exist extensions to enable this, if not supported by Chrome itself?

## Update

I have created a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=418406) for regular expression support in developer console search, since there appears to be no current support for it.

Comment: That'd be a clear "no", then. Do you have reasons to believe it could?

Comment: @Jongware Difficult to tell for sure. Maybe there exists extensions that'll add the functionality?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10912314/2564301) what you were looking for?

Comment: @Jongware No, I just want to search within the console, as with Ctrl+F, except with regular expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ctrl + F search with regular expressions does not exist. This functionality requires tight integration in the context of the developer tools, so if you don't like the alternative below, you have to look through the developer tools' source code, find the part that is responsible for implementing Ctrl+F, write a patch and apply the patch using https://stackoverflow.com/a/17044405/938089.

Click on the funnel icon and tick the Regex checkbox. Then you can filter console messages to only show messages that match your (case-insensitive) (JavaScript) regular expression.

[image]

Comment: I don't think the filter/funnel works with multiline regexes unfortunately.

Comment: Would you happen to know where to file a suggestion to implement console regex search in Chromium?

Comment: @aknuds1 Lack of multi-line regexes is not a real issue. Just use `(^|\n)` instead of `^` and `(\n|$)` instead of `$`. The regex applies to individual messages only though, so if you use `console.log(1);console.log(2)`, then you cannot use `0\n1` to find these two messages.

Comment: @aknuds1 If you want to file a suggestion, just file a request at https://crbug.com/new. Add a link to the issue after you've filed the issue, other readers may be interested in starring the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Well yeah, what I'm searching for spans several log messages, so the filter isn't going to do me much good.

Comment: @aknuds1 Here is a trick: Use the OR token to create a search that spans multiple lines. You will get more than usual, but it is better than having to dig through hundreds of lines by hand. To continue with my last example, it would look like `(^|\n)(0|1)($|\n)`.

Comment: I created an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=418406).

Comment: @aknuds1 If you want to get the feature as soon as possible, you can also contribute to the Developer tools yourself. See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/contributing if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll consider it at the very least :)

Answer (score 4):

Some chrome extension could support(at least partly) your requirement.

For example: "Chrome Regex Search" developed by [rshen](https://github.com/rogershen/chrome-regex-search). It looks like this:
[image]

To install it:

1. Access [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions)
2. Search the keyword "regex"
3. Click "ADD TO CHROME" button close to "Chrome Regex Search"

Comment: You can use [Ctrl + Shift + F] to fire up the regex search rather than default chrome search [Ctrl + F]