# How to find multiple keywords in source file from inspect element?

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, browser, web-inspector

I'm currently learning how to use web developer tools. So as a part of it I'm trying to find some multiple keywords at the search box which appears after pressing `ctrl + F`

[image]

**My question is**
How can I apply multiple search filters at a time uisng find. Like If i want to find more than 2 keywords in a source what is the best way to do it.

I've tried using regular expressions like so(I'm pretty sure syntax is wrong)

```
'Keyword1' & 'Keyword2'
```

Also tried

```
'Keyword1' | 'Keyword2'
```

Also tried

```
'Keyword1' or 'Keyword2'
```

But No use. I'm I missing anything here? I know we can use regular expressions but I'm looking for syntax to search multiple keywords. I'm pretty sure I've once used it a while ago . I don't remember exact expression to do so..

Comment: the search does not have a RegEx function built in it or some kind, its not possible to search more than 1 word at a time, you can see if there are extentions to add to your chrome, but i bet there is nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to search with regular expressions within Chrome's developer console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077976/is-it-possible-to-search-with-regular-expressions-within-chromes-developer-cons)

Comment: Hi @Zyfella Thanks for the suggestion...But That post only answers if we can use regular expressions or not...But I'm looking for expressions so that I can plug more than 2 keywords at a time

Answer (score 3):

Using regex search, you can do: `^(?=.*foo)(?=.*bar).*$`.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37692545/6911703

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is

```
keyword1|keyword2|keyword3
```

without spaces and quotations

In my machine first I needed to turn off the regex feature before searching, and than turn it on again. o.w. it got stucked

Comment: BTW, you could use this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find%20-regex-find-in-page/fddffkdncgkkdjobemgbpojjeffmmofb?hl=en