# How to track js file where script is defined through debugger in firefox/chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, firefox

I am looking the definition of javascript function `addHorizonLoadEvent`in following code, This function is defined in the separate file javascript file, So How I will track js file where the definition of that javascript is defined.

```
addHorizonLoadEvent(function() {
      show_hide_datepickers();
});
```

Please see the image, I found the definition of addHorizonLoadEvent, But I want to go to the file, How I will go? 
[image]

Comment: I guess you have to open all those external javascript files and search for it.

Comment: Add add a breakpoint at the line with the function you want and press `F11`, or use `CTRL + SHIFT + F` (in chrome) to search in all files for it. Also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828876/find-javascript-function-definition-in-chrome)

Comment: you could look at the library too.. https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/65db6d33aa40a202cd16ad60e08273f715a67745/horizon/templates/horizon/client_side/_script_loader.html

Comment: @toby - This should be an answer. Ctrl-Shift-F would have saved me so much time in the past. Nice trick. :)

Comment: @enhzflep before i found out about the shortcut i used to switch to FF just to search in all files so i know the feeling

Comment: @toby - haha. I do the same thing with C/C++ code and Visual Studio - only opening it if I need to debug something that's proving bothersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `CTRL + SHIFT + F` search in all files (for chrome) or `CTRL+ ALT + F`(for FF)
2. Add a breakpoint the line with the function and when that breakpoint is triggered (when that function is being executed) press `F11` to step into it.
3. If you're function is already in scope just `console.log` it (like `foo` **not** `foo()`) and click on the output)

Comment: I followed you instruction, Please see the updated question with image, As you told that after adding breakpoint you can press F11, But F11 is not working....

Comment: @NeelabhSingh The debugger has to reach that line of code for F11 to work. So somehow you have to trigger the `addHorizonLoadEvent` from the UI. As for the search part just clicking on one of the results should be enough.