# How to use chrome's debugger to locate a specific function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-debugger

I saw something that I'd like to implement on my site - it's the counter at the top-right corner of the page here: http://newatlas.com/chainless-chopper-mc2-bike/50836/#p476587 that counts the image you're on as, you scroll the page.

I'm sure I can modify it to do what I want for my site, if I could just see the code these guys are using!

Anyone know how to use the debugger to study another developer's code?

**Update**

This question was marked as a duplicate of [Find JavaScript function definition in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828876/find-javascript-function-definition-in-chrome), but that other question is not helpful in this case.

For one, the answers in that other question show you how to find a specific function name, *but I don't know the name of the function that's registered as the listener*.

For two, I don't think I should need to manually search the code in order to find the function. I'm sure there's a faster workflow for finding the code that's associated to an element's `click` event.

Comment: This question should be reopened. There are faster workflows for solving this task than the [existing question / answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828876/find-javascript-function-definition-in-chrome) that's linked to.

Comment: @KayceBasques Than put an answer in that dupe....

Comment: The answer doesn't apply to the duplicate question. This question can (and should) actually be phrased differently. I'll edit it when I'm on a laptop...

Comment: @KayceBasques yeah, perhaps I didn't phrase it the best way... rephrase however you see it getting a better answer, and please share the faster workflow you mentioned above.   
  
I checked out @ epascarello's answer, but it didn't help me track down the code in this instance. I don't know if was just me, if it was devtools that let me down, or if it the site itself doing something funny with React.

Comment: @epascarello I updated the question to explain why the other one is not helpful.

Comment: I'll be able to explain the faster workflow once this is re-opened.

Comment: @KayceBasques Thank you for the edit. You described the issue I had with it much better than how I had it. I ended up figuring out how to duplicate the behaviour I was looking for, and now my site has a similar counter, but I **definitely** want to learn your approach to a faster workflow. I'm hoping you'll be kind enough to share it.