# Can I see source of a method in Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I am debugging a webapp in Chrome and seeing something like `window.MyApp.getSomeStats()`. I can call it and see some output.

Is this possible to navigate to source of the code of this function/method in "Source" tab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find JavaScript function definition in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828876/find-javascript-function-definition-in-chrome)

Comment: You could just drop a break point on the line that calls the function and then "step into" the function call in the Chrome debugger. At least if it's a simple function (e.g. not an async function).